# How to execute all the feature files in Specflow from command prompt? And how to execute multiple feature files(i.e. 2 feature files )?

Tags: c#, nunit, specflow

Currently I am following the below syntax to run a single feature file from command prompt and its working fine

```
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxxx\packages\NUnit.ConsoleRunner.3.10.0\tools\nunit3-console.exe 

"C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\xxxx\UnitTestProject3\bin\Debug\TestAutomationV1.dll" --where "Description=='Reports' and cat==regression"
```

Comment: https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/Test-Selection-Language has some more details about this. Would it not just work to use "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\xxxx\UnitTestProject3\bin\Debug\TestAutomationV1.dll" --where "cat==regression"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to provide a common tag to both(all) of the feature files which you want to run and remove the "Description" attribute from the where clause in the command.